# How can 2D text be reflected onto 3D mesh surface?

Tags: text, 3d, 2d, mesh, geometry-surface

How can a 2D text be reflected onto 3D mesh surface in C# ?

Thanks in advance.

Cemo

Comment: Do you have any more specific question? What have you tried so far? What framework are you using (XNA, SlimDX, OpenGL)?

Answer (score 2):

Render the text to a texture and use the texture on the mesh.